# Function as an argument in Erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I'm trying to do something like this:

```erlang
-module(count).
-export([main/0]).
        
sum(X, Sum) -> X + Sum.

main() ->
    lists:foldl(sum, 0, [1,2,3,4,5]).
```

but see a warning and code fails:

```
function sum/2 is unused
```

How to fix the code?

**NB:** this is just a sample which illustrates problem, so there is no reason to propose solution which uses `fun`-expression.

Comment: Please post a self-contained and minimal version of your module with which the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Erlang, how do you invoke a function dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310382/in-erlang-how-do-you-invoke-a-function-dynamically)

Comment: can you try smth like this  `lists:foldl(fun(X, Sum) -> X + Sum end, 0, [1,2,3,4]).` ? because i don't have erlang interpreter at hand right now

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry , you can use http://ideone.com/ , though it is not so convenient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Erlang has slightly more explicit syntax for that:

```
-module(count).
-export([main/0]).

sum(X, Sum) -> X + Sum.
main() ->
    lists:foldl(fun sum/2, 0, [1,2,3,4,5]).
```

See also "[Learn you some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/higher-order-functions)":

> If function names are written without a parameter list then those names are interpreted as atoms, and atoms can not be functions, so the call fails.
>
> ...
>
> This is why a new notation has to be added to the language in order to let you pass functions from outside a module. This is what fun Module:Function/Arity is: it tells the VM to use that specific function, and then bind it to a variable.